# SSL Unsupported protocol error

Tags: tls, openssl, nmap

I'm trying to use ncat to connect between virtual windows7 and linux machines.

On linux:

```
ncat -vnl 4444 --ssl
```

On windows:

```
ncat -v 10.10.14.2 4444 --ssl
```

And when I try to connect from the client I get this error:

```
Ncat: Failed SSL connection from 10.10.14.2: error:1417D102:SSL routines:
tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol
```

Things I tried that did not work:

- Adding extra parameters --ssl-cert test-cert.pem --ssl-key test-key.pem
- Trying the other way around(linux client, windows server)
  I also googled a lot but, but I couldnt find a real solution, its all what might be wrong.

I can make this work using openssl s_client. But I need to use ncat, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what version is the ncat on windows? try getting an ncat of the same version as the linux one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the Linux ncat server will only use TLS1.2 for SSL connections. The Windows ncat is not using TLS1.2. This causes the unsupported protocol error.

I can replicate this issue using ncat version 7.60 on linux and connecting to it with openssl s_client using different protocol options. ncat 7.60 only uses tls1.2 for ssl connections.

To make this work using ncat, install the same version of ncat on both systems.

Comment: s_client is one option, changing ncat versions so that they match is another.

Comment: changing versions is not possible

Comment: @Spring Well, this answer explains that the versions are incompatible. If changing versions is not an option, you're out of luck. Is there a particular reason why you can't change the setup?

Comment: @Arminius that's pentest virtual lab environment, not recommended to update/downgrade any software

Answer (score 3):

Check in your `/ect/ssl/openssl.conf` if there is something that sets a minimum TLS version.

For example I found this at the bottom of my config:

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

I think your problem is that `MinProtocol` is set to only accept TCP 1.2

This is a more secure config, but if you are doing PWK then you may want to comment out this section so that revers shells are possible with ncat.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you are coming from PWK, check out Errata on their forum.

From their forum it seems that `openssl s_client` is acceptable, at least until this issue gets resolved on windows7 virtual machine.

In case you really **need** to use `ncat`, upgrade to up-to date version should help.

Comment: "I can make this work using openssl s_client. But I need to use ncat, how can I solve this problem?"  Can you clarify how your answer addresses the question?  It would help to flesh out the "how", and add a link for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an updated version of Kali the file is located at /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Go to the MinProtocol option and set it to TLSv1.0. a quick command to run would be

```
locate openssl.c
```